# Calling a native c++ dll with std::string argument from c++/cli

Tags: c++, c++-cli, interop, dllimport

I have a native c++ dll which I am trying to call from a c++/cli project.  Here's the dll's function

```
extern "C"
{
   int DLL_EXPORT Add(std::string s1, std::string s2, std::string s3)
   {
     [do stuff]
   }
}
```

Here's the reference in c++/cli:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
[DllImport("my_dll.dll")]
extern "C" int Add(std::string, std::string, std::string);
```

When I call the function, I marshal the String^ objects to std::string:

```
Add(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(stringA),
            msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(stringB),
            msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(stringC));
```

I get an access violation exception when the call to the DLL is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the DLL and the CLI compiled with the same compiler? In general, different compilers can have different definitions of `std::string` which can cause the error.

Therefore I wouldn't recommend in general to use `std::string` or any compiler specific types in DLL interface.

I guess that was the reason you make the function `extern "C"`. If it doesn't work without `extern "C"`, it will most likely not work (because of different mangling rules, which imply either different compiler or at least different `std::string` definition).

In this case I would prefer to create a wrapping function which takes `const char *` pointers.

Comment: Different compiler. Very astute of you.

Comment: It will in many cases not work even when called directly from C++, when different compilers are used (e.g. I suppose MSVC vs. mingw will have different definitions of std::string).

Comment: `extern "C"` is pretty hard to honor with `std::string` when you think about it...

Comment: You don't need to get as drastic a difference as MSVC vs. mingw to have problems passing std::string: Even different versions of MSVC will cause the issue.